# AM/PM ignored when loading dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, freebcp

I am using freebcp utility in unix to load a flat file to a SQL Server 2008 table

I have file content as `MAY 10 2013 01:00:01.000 PM` which is loaded to sql server table column (`datetime`).

when I select from that table i.e `select datecol from test` I get the output `2013-05-10 01:00:29.000`
but it should return `2013-05-10 13:00:29.000`

even when i `select convert(varchar,datecol,100) from test` I get the output `May 10 2013 12:00AM`

How can I import the value correctly?

Comment: The values you mentioned are very inconsistent: you mentioned May 10, then April 23; and 01:00:01 became 01:00:29. Having said that, this works for me (with US English settings): `declare @dt varchar(100) = 'MAY 10 2013 01:00:01.000 PM'; select cast(@dt as datetime);` You might want to load the data into a `varchar` column to verify that freebcp isn't removing the `PM` and it even may be easier to then convert that string value to datetime within the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can Reuse this C# code on Front-End side to convert Standard Time Format to Military Format.

```
public String convertToMilitaryFormatFromStandardTime(String standardTime)
    {
        String[] split1 = time.Split(':');
        String[] split2 = split1[1].Split(' ');
        if(split2[1] == "PM" || split2[1] == "AM")
        {
        split1[0] = (int.Parse(split1[0] + 12) + "");
        }
        return split1[0] + ":" + split2[0];    
    }
```